# How to add url to email body to open in Google Chrome by default

Tags: c#, angular, google-chrome, url, default-browser

I am working on a C#/Angular project. Due to some third party controls, some of the website features do not work on IE. There is an email which goes out containing link to a page. When I click the link it is opening by default in IE. Is there a way I can default it to open in Google Chrome?
Here is my code and url syntax:

```
string ProjectURL = String.Format("<a href=\"https://dev.mylink.net/MyApp/#/mycomponent\">Project link</a>");


string EmailBody = "<p>" + ManagerName + " (" + ManagerID + "),</p><p>The request " + ReqNumber + " submitted by " + UserName + ", on " + CreationDate + " is ready for Approval.</p><p>Please visit the following URL to Approve this request:" + ProjectURL + "</p>";
```

P.S. The url contains a "#" as well.

Comment: Try to Simply replace `http` with `googlechrome` and `https` with `googlechromes`. This means:

`http://www.google.com/` becomes `googlechrome://www.google.com/` and similarly 
`https://dev.mylink.net` becomes `googlechromes://dev.mylink.net`

Comment: Did not work. I believe that recommendation is for iOS

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a way to do it since the default browser defined in the client computer.